# How to prevent aggressive matching of single characters typed in Teams input box to Teams Bot Commands that disrupts typing of messages?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

A Teams bot manifest file is allowed to provide a sections called Commands (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-commands-menu?tabs=desktop%2Cdotnet)   These then appear as suggestions in the input box when a user is chatting with a bot.

The most recent (~late Sep 2021) Teams client release for Desktop and Web seems to have change the manner in which the suggestions popup when a user begins to type a message in the input box.   Now it seems that as soon as one clicks to get focus on the input box the suggestions popup.   (It is not obvious to most regular end users how to dismiss these suggestions.  The answer is to use the Escape key but most users end up clicking on these suggestions as the only way to dismiss them.  Some of these commands may be disruptive i.e cause end of a session).    The previous behaviour seemed to be that only when a user started to type something that would match the command will the suggestions popup. Now they popup on gaining focus alone.

[image]

In addition it seems that the new behaviour is to aggressively match any typed character in the input box with the command.  So for example if the command is HELP, then either h, e, l or p typed in the input box will bring up the suggestion box  (rather than say h or he or hel).   This essentially stops most users from typing a free form text message.  Most bots are conversational with only a few suggestion items.

As a result the Teams bots that have any Commands at all have suddenly become virtually unusable in a conversational sense with frequent suggestion popups since commands contain common characters as well.

Starting a sentence with P (for example user was going to type Please.. ) brings up the suggestion popup for Help command even though P is not the start of the Help command.
[image]

Is there a way to specify better pattern matching in the Commands or to better control this behaviour from the bot code (unlikely since this is a local Teams client behaviour) or from the Teams Manifest file settings?

(Rolling out new manifest files across 100+ customer tenants is a pain given that a Teams Admin has to do this, and it may take 48 hours to get rolled out)

Answer (score 0):

It is by design. There is no workaround available for it.

Comment: Well, Seems more like a bug that a single letter will match a command even if it is the middle of the command text. Why did the design change just recently?  Its not mentioned in any release notes.  It has crippled  the user experience  for  most conversational bots starting in  last 2 weeks as user has to dismiss the suggestions before they can type a message.

Comment: So we have find out two behavior on Desktop and Web. On desktop it is only showing the suggestion if it match starting with first letter and on web it is taking from middle.